# Github Actions Workflows keeps on running for an infinite time until fails

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

**I created a github actions workflow which runs my nodejs server on locahost and runs a test case which checks for server response. But in the actions option in github, the workflow doesn't seem to stop excecuting and keeps on running for a prolonged time.**

This is my workflow--

```
name: Build and Test

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14  # Adjust the Node.js version as needed

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Start Express.js Server
      run: npm start  # Use the appropriate start command for your server

    - name: Wait for Server to Start
      run: |
        while [ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://localhost:3000)" != "200" ]; do sleep 1; done

    - name: Run Tests
      run: npm test  # Replace with your actual test command
```

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my test.js

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const app = require('./server');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Server', () => {
  it('should return "Hello, World!" when / endpoint is accessed', (done) => {
    chai.request(app)
      .get('/')
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.text).to.equal('Hello, World!');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

*The test case is running fine in my local machine but not in the actual github workflow.*